# javascript touch swipe function not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a swipe function to the gallery of my website for weeks. The best I found was this http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents3.shtml

So my code at the moment looks like this:
.html:

```
[...]
<body>
    [...]
    <section id="Galerie">
        <div id="swipegallery" class="touchgallery">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/Startseite_1.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/Startseite_3.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/Startseite_1.jpg">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/Startseite_3.jpg">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    [...]
    <script src="swipe.js" async></script>
</body>
```

.css:

```
.touchgallery {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 800px; /* default gallery width */
    height: 600px; /* default gallery height */
    background: #eee;
    margin: auto;
}
 
.touchgallery ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out; /* image transition. Change 100ms to desired transition duration */
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
 
.touchgallery ul li{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}
 
.touchgallery ul li img{ /* CSS for images within gallery */
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1000px; /* make each image responsive, so its native width can occupy up to 100% of gallery's width, but not beyond */
    height: auto;
}
```

.js:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var element = document.getElementById('swipegallery'); // Referenziere den hauptsächlichen DIV Container der Galerie
    var galerieBreite = element.offsetWidth;
    var unorderedList = element.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    var anzahlListenPunkte = unorderedList.getElementsByTagName('li').length, 
        derzeitigerIndex = 0, 
        unorderedListLeft = 0;
    unorderedList.style.width = galerieBreite * anzahlListenPunkte; // Setze die Gesamtbreite von ungeordneteListe durch Breite des Bildes multipliziert mit der Anzahl der Bilder
    
    ontouch(element, function(evt, richtung, phase, swipetype, abstand){
        if (phase == 'start'){ // bei touchstart
            unorderedListLeft = parseInt(unorderedList.style.left) || 0; // Initialisiere unorderedList mit dem Abstand links von UL
        }
        else if (phase == 'move' && (richtung =='left' || richtung =='right')){ //  Wird ausgeführt wenn eine horizontale Bewegung stattfindet
            var gesamtAbstand = abstand + unorderedListLeft; // Berechne den neuen Abstand für UL durch Bewegung des Fingers
            unorderedList.style.left = Math.min(gesamtAbstand, (derzeitigerIndex+1) * galerieBreite) + 'px'; // Setze neuen Abstand von links aus
        }
        else if (phase == 'end'){ // bei touchend
            if (swipetype == 'left' || swipetype == 'right'){ // Wenn die Bewegung horizontal war
                derzeitigerIndex = (swipetype == 'left')? Math.min(derzeitigerIndex+1, anzahlListenPunkte-1) : Math.max(derzeitigerIndex-1, 0); // Gebe neuen Index für Bild aus
            }
            unorderedList.style.left = -derzeitigerIndex * galerieBreite + 'px'; // Bewege zum neuen Bild
        }
    }) // Ende der Funktion ontouch
}, false)

function ontouch(el, callback){
 
    var touchsurface = el,
    dir,
    swipeType,
    startX,
    startY,
    distX,
    distY,
    threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
    restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
    allowedTime = 500, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
    elapsedTime,
    startTime,
    handletouch = callback || function(evt, dir, phase, swipetype, distance){}
 
    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        dir = 'none'
        swipeType = 'none'
        dist = 0
        startX = touchobj.pageX
        startY = touchobj.pageY
        startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
        handletouch(e, 'none', 'start', swipeType, 0) // fire callback function with params dir="none", phase="start", swipetype="none" etc
        e.preventDefault()
 
    }, false)
 
    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        distX = touchobj.pageX - startX // get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        distY = touchobj.pageY - startY // get vertical dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
        if (Math.abs(distX) > Math.abs(distY)){ // if distance traveled horizontally is greater than vertically, consider this a horizontal movement
            dir = (distX < 0)? 'left' : 'right'
            handletouch(e, dir, 'move', swipeType, distX) // fire callback function with params dir="left|right", phase="move", swipetype="none" etc
        }
        else{ // else consider this a vertical movement
            dir = (distY < 0)? 'up' : 'down'
            handletouch(e, dir, 'move', swipeType, distY) // fire callback function with params dir="up|down", phase="move", swipetype="none" etc
        }
        e.preventDefault() // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
    }, false)
 
    touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
        if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime){ // first condition for awipe met
            if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
                swipeType = dir // set swipeType to either "left" or "right"
            }
            else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint){ // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
                swipeType = dir // set swipeType to either "top" or "down"
            }
        }
        // Fire callback function with params dir="left|right|up|down", phase="end", swipetype=dir etc:
        handletouch(e, dir, 'end', swipeType, (dir =='left' || dir =='right')? distX : distY)
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
}
 
// USAGE:
/*
ontouch(el, function(evt, dir, phase, swipetype, distance){
 // evt: contains original Event object
 // dir: contains "none", "left", "right", "top", or "down"
 // phase: contains "start", "move", or "end"
 // swipetype: contains "none", "left", "right", "top", or "down"
 // distance: distance traveled either horizontally or vertically, depending on dir value
 
 if ( phase == 'move' && (dir =='left' || dir == 'right') )
  console.log('You are moving the finger horizontally by ' + distance)
})
*/
```

But of course swiping does not work. At the beginning there was not even an image shown so as I tried to fix it I translated the comments of .addEventListener into german (The mistake the referenced website did was a "+ 'px'" for unorderedList.style.width). I tried some stuff, but I could not really make any significant progress.

I would be very thankful if someone can give me working touch functions for .js or find some of the stupid mistakes I probably made.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
let xTouchDown, yTouchDown; 

document.querySelector("#swipegallery").addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
    let firstTouch = e.touches[0];                                      
    xTouchDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
    yTouchDown = firstTouch.clientY; 
});

document.querySelector("#swipegallery").addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
    if (!xTouchDown || !yTouchDown) return;
    let xTouchUp = e.touches[0].clientX;                                    
    let yTouchUp = e.touches[0].clientY;
    let xDifferential = xTouchDown - xTouchUp;
    let yDifferential = yTouchDown - yTouchUp;

    if (Math.abs(xDifferential) > Math.abs(yDifferential)){
        if ( xDifferential > 0 ){
            //swiping left
            console.log("left swipe");
        } 
        else{
            //swiping right
            console.log("right swipe");
        }                       
    }
    xTouchDown = null;
    yTouchDown = null;                                             
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it doesn't work at all